# UIAlertController как отделить кнопки от Title

Tags: ios, objective-c

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. При сознании UIAlertController кнопки Yes\NO не отделились от титульника. Как их отделить(например как на рис.2).

Мой код:

```
 UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                             message:@"message"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                            handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                              //
                            }];
[yesButton setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];

UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"NO"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                            //
                           }];

[alert addAction:yesButton];
[alert addAction:noButton];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: какполучилось у меня]

[image: как я хочу]

Answer (score 2):

Если скриншот с симулятора, есть вероятность, что линия просто не прорисовалась. Попробуйте запустить на другом симуляторе или на устройстве – линия должна быть, хоть и не видна в данном конкретном симуляторе. Так часто бывает с тонкими линиями